# Pacman: "error: target not found"

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Several times I updated `pacman -Syy` , `pacman -Syu` and some other commands. 
I have multilib source uncommented in `pacman.conf`.
My last thoughts were about `pacman-key`, I was trying to change keyserver in `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/gnu.conf`, run `pacman-key --refresh-keys` and `pacman-key --populate archlinux` but it didn't help me. Was googling a lot, but I guess I need to ask here.
`pacman -S xorg` works, but `pacman -S yaourt` and several others not

UPD: `pacman.conf`

```
 #
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
#HookDir     = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
#UseDelta    = 0.7
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Never
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Arch Linux
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinux`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

#[testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# If you want to run 32 bit applications on your x86_64 system,
# enable the multilib repositories as required here.

#[multilib-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

Trying to install

```
 sudo pacman -S light 
 error: target not found: light 
 sudo pacman -S alsamixer
 error: target not found: alsamixer
```

Comment: yaourt is not in the official repositories, so pacman will not find it. Read how the AUR works.

Comment: But it was only an example. I also cannot install alsamixer, xbacklight and another apps.

Comment: Paste your pacman.conf and the full command and output.

Comment: Pasted conf and commands

Comment: There is no package "light" nor "alsamixer". Paste the output of `pacman -Syu alsa-utils`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `yaourt` , open the terminal and run

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/package-query.git
cd package-query
makepkg -si
cd ..
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yaourt.git
cd yaourt
makepkg -si
cd ..
```

Save and run;

```
sudo pacman -Sy yaourt base-devel fakeroot
yaourt -Syu --devel --aur
```

`alsamixer` is a part of `alsa-utils` , `light` package should be installed from AUR

Comment: That repo is full of broken packages: advising anyone ot enable it is doing them a disservice.

Comment: @jasonwryan i have used this repo for a long time , I don't know that

Comment: @jasonwryan can you provide some link , please

Comment: There is no single link, there is a long history of broken packages documented on the boards and on IRC...